# Replacing for loop by map

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace the for loop below by a map function,
I assume it must be something like map(inBetween, `input.split("\n")`) but when I do it my hours dictionary stays unchanged. I feel like it's not even entering the function.

Does someone know how to make it work?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.5

input='''5
1 8
2 3
4 23
4 6
2 23'''

hours = {}
for time in range(1,25):
    hours[time] = 0
def inBetween(line):
    print(line)
    current = int(line.split(" ")[0])
    while current < int(line.split(" ")[1]):
        hours[current] +=1
        current += 1
for entree in range(1, int(input.split("\n")[0])+1):
        inBetween(input.split("\n")[entree])

print(hours)
```

Comment: That's because a `map` in python-3.x works *lazy*, materialize it with `list(map(..))`

Comment: Is there a better way if I don't need the result as a new list? I just need to apply the function to each element in the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem already said in a comment, `map` is lazy in Python 3. Instead of applying the function to all items immediately and returning a list, as was the case in Python 2, `map` will return a generator instead which you need to iterate over in order to actually perform the transformation:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def square(x):
        print('Calculating square of', x)
        return x * x

>>> res = map(square, lst)
>>> res
<map object at 0x0000029C2E4B2CC0>
```

As you can see, the function does not run, and `res` is some “map object” instead (which is the map generator). We have to iterate this generator first in order to actually generate the values and call the function:

```
>>> for x in res:
        print(x)

Calculating square of 1
1
Calculating square of 2
4
Calculating square of 3
9
```

If you want to get a list back, you can also just call `list()` on the result to immediately call the function for every element:

```
>>> list(map(square, lst))
Calculating square of 1
Calculating square of 2
Calculating square of 3
[1, 4, 9]
```

---

Note though, that your case is not really suited for `map`. As far as I can tell from your code and your input, the first line of your input is a single number that contains the amount of lines that follow which need to be processed.

So in your case, unless you want to actively ignore that first line (and just handle *every* line), you shouldn’t use `map` here.

However, you can make your code a lot simpler (and more efficient) by storing the results from those `split` calls. For example:

```
lines = input.split('\n')
for i in range(1, int(lines[0]) + 1):
    inBetween(lines[i])
```

Here, you’re just splitting the input *once* instead of once on every iteration.

As for your `inBetween` function, you can also use a for loop here which makes it a bit simpler:

```
def inBetween(line):
    # using a tuple unpacking to get both values from the line at once
    start, stop = line.split(' ') 
    for h in range(int(start), int(stop)):
        hours[h] += 1
```

Finally, there isn’t actually any benefit from your `inBetween` function here. Since it’s mutating global state (the `hours` dictionary), it’s not really useful outside of its exact context, so you could simply inline the functionality here. You could then even extract the logic, so you get a function that just processes the input and returns you that `hours` dictionary. Combined with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) this can actually look pretty nice:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def getHours(lines):
    hours = defaultdict(int)
    for i in range(1, int(lines[0]) + 1):
        start, stop = lines[i].split(' ')
        for h in range(int(start), int(stop)):
            hours[h] += 1
    return dict(hours)
```

And that’s already everything:

```
>>> getHours(input.split('\n'))
{ 1: 1,  2: 3,  3: 2,  4: 4,  5: 4,  6: 3,  7: 3,  8: 2,  9: 2, 10: 2,
 11: 2, 12: 2, 13: 2, 14: 2, 15: 2, 16: 2, 17: 2, 18: 2, 19: 2, 20: 2,
 21: 2, 22: 2 }
```